# How can I apply a ring-shaped median filter to an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

The default matlab function medfilt2 uses a rectangular mask.

Thanks guys

Comment: With ring you mean a circle with a hole in? You mean to use that as mask, or have a ring shaped area in your image which has median filtering done with the rest of the image staying unaffected?

Comment: @natan lucky we can't downvote a comment...

Comment: yes, the question is badly phrased, it still doesn't deserve -5 votes, let alone 2 close votes. it is a legitimate question (as much as I understood it) and unless there is a duplicate one, all the author needs to do is to make it more detailed. Besides that http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments

Comment: the bright side of these -5 votes is that I can shoot for a reversal badge now ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`ordfilt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ordfilt2.html) .

For example, if your "ring" is just defined by:

```
ring= fspecial('gaussian',21,1)
ring = ring>eps & ring<1e-9
```

[image]

then:

```
order=sum(ring(:))/2;
B = ordfilt2(A,order,ring);
```

replaces each element in A by the order-th element in the sorted set of neighbors specified by the nonzero elements in the ring domain.
Here I chose 'order' to be half the total # of the pixels in the ring.